# What python do if i put a module's name in eval()?

Tags: python, eval

I notice that the following outcome:

```
from mymodule import test
prog = ['test']
exe = eval(prog[0])
print(type(exe))
```

it prints < class 'module' >  !!!

I don't know why it woks like that and i don't see any tutorial explain such code.
Could anyone explain it for me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

Comment: The import statement puts the name `test` in scope, so `eval` can then see it. What else would you expect to happen?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Why is this surprising? It prints the same thing as `type(test)`? `eval` evaluates python expressions... What exactly do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

It works just like if you typed a module name without eval:

```
import math
print(type(math))
# output <class 'module'>
```

and just as [Jamie Bull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1706564/jamie-bull), it's specified in the documentation